# How to translate CSS3 code into jQuery in WordPress

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I can achieve the effect I want by using this CSS3 code:

```
article .post-cover{
transition: opacity .9s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: opacity .9s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: opacity .9s ease-in-out;
}

article:hover .post-cover{ opacity:1;}
```

But When I tried to translate that to jQuery in the header.php file using the following, it doesn't work:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $( "article.post-cover" ).hover(function() {
    $( this ).fadeTo( "slow", 1 );
    });
</script>
```

I also tried this, and failed:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $( "div.post-cover" ).hover(function() { //div is the element directly
                                             //encompassing the .post-cover class
    $( this ).fadeTo( "slow", 1 );
    });
</script>
```

I need to use jQuery or javascript for compatibility purposes, please help.

And how can I control the speed of fadeTo?

Thank you.
yulius

Comment: what do you mean by **"div is the element directly encompassing the .post-cover class"**?,on the second code. can you show the html?

Comment: this is what the element looks like, when I "inspect"ed it through chrome: <div class="post-cover post-cover-114 stag-image--none"></div>

Comment: does the code for the slide show use something like **$('element')...** or **jQuery("element")...**? because i don't think the first works in wordpress

Comment: @bkVnet I am sorry for replying so late, been busy these couple of days. The slideshow code actually do use the $ instead of the jQuery. Funny thing is that the slideshow works while the codes suggested in this thread doesn't

Comment: you don't need to specify the jQuery file's path in your as WordPress comes with jQuery and you also have to use *wp_enqueue_script("jquery");* at the head section of your header.php file. see [here](https://digwp.com/2009/06/including-jquery-in-wordpress-the-right-way/)

Comment: a modification of @Hoopson2 's solution seems to work somewhat after I moved the script to footer.php. It looks like this: $("article").mouseenter(function() {
        $(".post-cover").fadeTo(1000, 1);
    }).mouseleave(function() {
        $(".post-cover").fadeTo(1000,0.5);
    }); but problem is, unlike the CSS3 version above, it seems like when I hover over one of the post, all posts fade in and out at the same time. I only want one of the post to fade in and out (the one I hovered over). What do you think?

Comment: if all of your posts have the same css class *post-cover* then that is going to happen. It would be better to post the relevant part of your html to your question.

Answer (score 0):

In CSS, you are applying style to `.post-cover` on `article` hover. But Your Jquery is doing hover on itself `post-cover`.
Try this:

```
$("article").hover(function() {       
  $('.post-cover').fadeTo( "slow", 1);
});
```

Comment: Thank you @Rajesh Kumar, Unfortunately, that doesn't work. I am using wordpress, I am wondering if that is causing problems? I inserted the jQuery code in header.php. Does that make a difference?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using mouseenter and mouseleave events instead of css:hover.  Here's a start:

```
   $(".article").mouseenter(function() {
        $(".post-cover").css("opacity", "1").css("transition", "opacity .9s ease-in-out").css( <you other styles> );
    }).mouseleave(function() {
         $(".post-cover").css( <you non-hover-styled css here> );
    });
```

Comment: Thank you @user9999999, Unfortunately, that doesn't work. I am using wordpress, I am wondering if that is causing problems? I inserted the jQuery code in header.php. Does it matter at all?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to select the element you want to hover on and call `.fadeTo()` on your class inside the function. If you want the class to fade out and then return to full opacity I would use mouseenter & mouseleave. In `.fadeTo()` you can pass the duration in a number(ms) or string(slow/fast/etc) to control speed, and the opacity.

Something similar to this:

```
$("div").mouseenter(function() {
        $(".post-cover").fadeTo( 1000, 0.5);
    }).mouseleave(function() {
         $(".post-cover").fadeTo( 1000, 1);
    });
```

Here is a [Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Reedpm2/8kv30jhx/3/).

Comment: Thank you @Hoopson2, Unfortunately, that doesn't work. I am using wordpress, I am wondering if that is causing problems? I inserted the jQuery code in header.php. Does it matter at all?

Comment: @yulius I am not extremely familiar with Wordpress; however, it seems that you shouldn't just add jQuery into the header.php. You may want to check out emaples/tutorials on how to implement jQuery when using Wordpress. Hopefully something like this can help get you started, [Adding javascript/jQuery to your Wordpress](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/adding-jquery-to-wordpress-theme-the-right-way).

Comment: Hi @Hoopson2 Thank you for the suggestion, I will take a look at it. I guess taking the lazy way out does have some limits afterall.

Comment: your solution works when I changed the "div" to "article". Actually using "div" works too, but it is much much slower than just using "article", probably because it goes through many divs before finally executing the fades. BUT the problem with your solution is that when I hover over 1 post, EVERY single posts fades in and out. Note that my CSS3 works as intended and I am using article.post-cover too, what could be the problem? I only want the post that I am hovering over to fade in and out

Comment: @yulius I had copy and pasted the code example from my fiddle which is why it still had "div". You can change that to article and try changing the  selector in the fadeTo() to be $(this) so it only fades the artice you are hovering at that time. [Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8kv30jhx/7/)

Answer (score 0):

As far as i could remember the `'$'` shortcut for jQuery doesn't work in WordPress. So you might try something like:

```
jQuery( "div.post-cover" ).hover(function() { //div is the element directly
    jQuery( this ).fadeTo("slow", 1 );
});
```

> And how can I control the speed of fadeTo?

From the jQuery documentation of `fadeTo( String,Number duration, Number opacity...`

> *duration* - A **string or number** determining how long the animation will run. Durations are given in **milliseconds**(if a number).

```
jQuery( this ).fadeTo( 1000, 1 );//fadeTo for 1 second
jQuery( this ).fadeTo( 500, 1 );//fadeTo for 500ms
```

Comment: Hi @bkVnet, Hoopson2 's solution sort of worked, can you please help me with it, the details are in my reply in Hoopson2's solution. Thank you.